Evaluating a pretrained model in pytorch
I’m trying to evaluate a pre-trained model that I trained with the PPO example from the pytorch tutorials website but I'm failing to obtain the same results as during training.
I’ve saved the model (in the training script) with:
model_weights_filename = "models/ppo_example_model_weights_500k.pth"
torch.save(policy_module.state_dict(), model_weights_filename)

and loaded them with:
model_weights_filename = "models/ppo_example_model_weights_500k.pth"
policy_module.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_weights_filename))

in my evaluation script.
Finally, I'm using the same rollout function as in the tutorial (the policy_module is defined equal to the training script):
""" Evaluate """
policy_module.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    for _ in range(10):
        eval_rollout = env.rollout(1000, policy_module)

In some rare cases I’m getting good results, but most of the time the actor survives only a few steps instead of 999.
Edit for Clarification:
I’ve trained the model for 1 million iterations, up to the point where the agent survives 999 steps pretty much all the time.
Am I missing something crucial here?

How many steps are you actually getting? The tutorial itself shows a plot at the end with ~40 steps by end of training. Quite a bit less than 999

@Karl I’ve trained the model for 1 million iterations, up to the point where the agent survives 999 steps (the maximum) pretty much all the time.
